# Getting website by website code issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, websites

This is my code:

```
 $website = Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_collection')->load('code', $code)->getData();
```

where `$code` is my website code. In the `$website` variable at the moment I got all of the websites. I just need only one, by using it's code. How can i make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get data like this :

```
$websites = Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_collection')->load()->addFieldToFilter( 'code', $code);

foreach($websites as $website)
{
    // Get Data Of that website here
}
```